# Touchpad not working in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mouse, touchpad, lenovo

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 in my Lenovo IdeaPad 330 and from the installed Ubuntu touchpad is not working when I run the command `xinput list` there isn't any touchpad device showing there.

Someone told me that it is kernel version doesn't support this with new devices.

Comment: There's an answer on this link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1266880/touchpad-and-wifi-not-working-on-lenovo-ideapad-3-14iil05-ubuntu-16-04-06/1404386#1404386

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem on a lubuntu 18.04 just doing a upgrade:

```
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```