# Touchpad and WiFi not working on Lenovo IdeaPad 3 14IIL05 (Ubuntu 16.04.06)

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, mouse, touchpad, lenovo

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04.6 version on Lenovo IdeaPad 3 14IIL05, After installation laptop's keyboard, touchpad and WiFi are not working. I reinstalled xserver-xorg-input-all package and also updated the kernel version but still facing the same issue. I have executed xinput command, touchpad and keyboard are not detecting.

Comment: Try Ubuntu 20.04 from LiveUSB.

Comment: I tried from Live USB with 16.04, 18.04, and 20.04 but still facing the same issue.

Comment: Then ask separate questions about Wi-Fi and the touchpad. I am afraid the touchpad is simply not supported. But there may be some ways. Without knowing the hardware it is impossible to tell.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the information.

Comment: H/w Specification: 1.2 GHz with Turbo Boost Upto 3.4 GHz Intel Core i3-1005G1 10th Gen Processor, 12 GB DDR4 RAM, 1 TB HDD, Integrated Graphics

Comment: This specification doesn't include wireless device or the touchpad model.

Comment: Does your ubuntu detect your wireless card? Check it in terminal using ```iwconfig``` .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [lenovo IdeaPad-3-14ARE05 Touchpad not working. Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1249298/lenovo-ideapad-3-14are05-touchpad-not-working-ubuntu-20-04)

Answer (score 0):

You can go to "Software & Updates" and then additional drivers tab to check which drivers are needed to be installed.

Or you can use this command to get a list of available drivers:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
```

You can install them manually, or you can use:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Comment: I checked in Software & Updates but it showing No additional drivers are available. Also executed autoinstall command but No drivers found for automatic installation.

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix the touchpad:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Replace line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="pci=nocrs quiet splash"`

Save file `/etc/default/grub`

Execute `sudo update-grub`

Reboot.

This is commented here:

[lenovo IdeaPad-3-14ARE05 Touchpad not working. Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1249298/lenovo-ideapad-3-14are05-touchpad-not-working-ubuntu-20-04)